# Dropdown does not show values

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a drop down with multi select options (don't look at the content, its for tests only).

I added css links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

and scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Dropdown looks like:

```
<select  th:field="*{cars}" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Role</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><br/>
```

but after run it looks like:

[image: drop down view]

When I remove class attribute I am getting normal select with multiple option:

[image: drop down without class attribute]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to implement your script tag for jQuery correct:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then your code is running.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select  th:field="*{cars}" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Role</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><br/>
```

Comment: (In case it's not obvious at first glance: there was a missing `</script>` tag.)

Comment: I have to confirm, after add </script> instead /> everything works. Thanks :)